# Formulate square of a function in Mixed Integer Linear Programming using pulp

Tags: linear-programming, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

I have a linear equation Ax = b. I am trying to minimize (Ax-b)^2 using pulp in Python. Dimensions of A are (1000, 500) and b is (1000,).

So far I have tried this:

```
import pulp
mse = pulp.LpProblem("Example_Problem", LpMinimize)
vars = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('x', range(len(A[0])), lowBound=0,upBound =1, 
                             cat='Integer')
for row, rhs in zip(A, b):
    mse += sum([row[i]*vars[i] for i in range(len(row))]) - rhs
```

How do i use the square for the function mse. If i try:

```
mse += (sum([row[i]*vars[i] for i in range(len(row))]) - rhs)**2
```

I get this error:

*unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'LpAffineExpression' and 'int'*

Answer (score 1):

Pulp is for linear models only. You created a nonlinear model.

In theory you can solve this by forming normal equations (see a statistics book): you get a linear system of equations. This can be solved with an LP solver but unfortunately this method is not very reliable.

A better way to use an LP model is to replace the square of the deviations by the absolute value of the deviations. This will give you an LP (see [link](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2017/11/lp-and-lad-regression.html)). This method is sometimes used to get more robust estimates that are less affected by outliers.

With your added constraint that x must assume integer values, you end up with a MIP model.